# ajax/jquery help - displaying a dynamically created list item when clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to the ajax world and was hoping you guys can help.

Currently, I can dynamically create a list of items via ajax. The problem I'm running into is that when I click on a list item created by ajax, it displays all of the list items.  I only want to display the list item i clicked on.

Below is a code snippet to give you an idea of what i'm trying to do.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

$('div.calendar_content').click(function() {
    $('#product_list ol li').remove();
        day_num = $(this).prev().text();
        if(day_num.length == 1)
        {
            day_num = 0 +day_num;
        }
        today_date = <?=$year ?> +'-'+<?= $month; ?>+'-' +day_num;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?= site_url()?>/admin/post_rooms",
            data: {'today_date':today_date},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data.returned_val, function(key,value){
                    content = '<li id='+value.res_id+'>Dorm Room '+ value.room_no +' '+value.first_name+' '+value.last_name+'</li>';    
                    $(content).appendTo("#product_list ol");
                });
            }
        }); 
   });

   $("#product_list ol ").click(function(){
        alert($('#product_list ol li').text());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#product_list ol li").on('click', function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your help.  I tried it but received an error in firebug:  $("#product_list ol li").on is not a function

Comment: Maybe your jQuery version is too old, they added the `on` feature in v1.7 (check http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data){  
    $.each(data.returned_val, function(key,value){
        content = '<li id='+value.res_id+'>Dorm Room '+ value.room_no +' '+value.first_name+' '+value.last_name+'</li>';    
        $(content).appendTo("#product_list ol");
    });
    //The hiding part
    $("#product_list ol > li").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings().hide();
    });
}
```

In this way you register a click event on the list items afer you generated them. When you click on the item the function takes all the item's [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and hides them.